# PrincipalContext - I Can't connect to a local openldap server

Tags: c#, openldap, principalcontext

I have installed an `openldap for windows` server and I use `LDAPAdmin` to connect to it by its default values :

```
Server=ldap://localhost:389
Base:dc=maxcrc,dc=com
UserName:cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com
Password:secret
```

Now I want to use `PrincipalContext` to add users to my `ou=People`
The problem is I can't even connect to the server using PrincipalContext. I have searched the Net and found a lot of answers on how to connect to a ldap server but none of them are working for me.I keep getting a `NullReferenceException` or `ServerNotFoundException` for different combination of provided parameters for PrincipalContext constructor.
I thought I could use PrincipalContext as one of the follows :

```
new PirncipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"maxcrc.com","dc=maxcrc,dc=com")
```

or

```
new PrincipalContext(ContextType.ApplicationDirectory,"localhost:389","dc=maxcrc,dc=com")
```

but none of them are working.Some say that I should provide username and password so I did that but I keep getting exception.

So please tell me how can I use PrincipalContext to connect to openldap ?

P.S. My computer is already joined to an Active Directory domain controller.

Comment: Did you use `DirectoryEntry` or `PirncipalContext` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the [official documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states:

> *The System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace provides uniform access and manipulation of user, computer, and group security principals across the multiple principal stores: **Active Directory** Domain Services (AD DS), **Active Directory** Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS), and Machine SAM (MSAM). System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement manages directory objects independent of the System.DirectoryServices namespace.*

Those classes are useful for **Active Directory** only - they are **not** portable to other, "generic" LDAP stores.

If you need to support OpenLDAP, either use `DirectoryEntry` and those functions, or use the lower level `System.DirectoryServices.Protocol` (bare-bones LDAP) layer.