# Connecting to LDAP server throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to connect to the online test LDAP server specified [here](https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/) using `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` like this:

```
try
{
    using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "ldap.forumsys.com:389", "dc=example,dc=com", "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com", "password"))
    {
         using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(ctx )))
         {
              foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll().Take(usersCount))
              {
                 DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
              }
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

But it throws the following exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Could you please tell what is wrong with my code and how to be able to connect to that LDAP server?

PS: I am able to connect to that server using Apache Directory Studio

Stack Trace :

> at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ReadServerConfig(String serverName, ServerProperties& properties)
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoServerVerifyAndPropRetrieval()
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext..ctor(ContextType contextType, String name, String container, ContextOptions options, String userName, String password)
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext..ctor(ContextType contextType, String name, String container, String userName, String password)
>      at ConsoleApp1.Program.GetGroups(String userName) in C:\Users\Simple Code\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 48

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: in simple terms it failed to create ctx with the principalcontext you gave it

Comment: @Fildor You mixed it up. NullPointerException => java, NullReferenceException => .NET

Comment: @Simple Code can you share the real code of `// some code here`?

Comment: @Ferus7 It's throwing that exception on PrincipalContext constructor

Comment: Usually I use `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectorySearcher` to connect to LDAP

Comment: @Ferus7 That's the old, pre-.NET 4.0 way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @BugFinder That duplicate doesn't work when the exception is thrown by the framework itself. The OP cannot debug nor change that code

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto you can still check that ctx (in this case) is not null, or trap for it

Comment: @BugFinder The OP commented that the constructor call throws the error, not that `ctx` is null

Comment: @SimpleCode Are you using .NET Framework or .NET Core?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto .NET Framework4.6

Comment: in which exactly line is the exception fired? maybe is here `result.GetUnderlyingObject()`?

Comment: @Ferus7 at "using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "ldap.forumsys.com:389", "dc=example,dc=com", "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com", "password"))"

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto actually he didnt until 1 min ago ... but you can still place a try loop round the whole thing.

Comment: @BugFinder not really: "@Ferus7 It's throwing that exception on PrincipalContext constructor – Simple Code 13 mins ago"

Comment: @SimpleCode It seems (from a .NET Core issue, though) that it can throw a NRE if the domain cannot be found. Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PrincipalContext - I Can't connect to a local openldap server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988638/principalcontext-i-cant-connect-to-a-local-openldap-server)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto language doesn't make a difference in this case.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yes about 1 min before I posted that he had 1 min ago...  However a try/catch round that whole thing would still be valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988638/principalcontext-i-cant-connect-to-a-local-openldap-server), the problem could be that you try to connect to an **Apache Directory Studio** with the class `PrincipalContext` that not supports this OpenLDAP,

so one way to go is using the `DirectoryEntry` class

Comment: DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("ldap.forumsys.com:389", "cn=gauss,ou=mathematicians,dc=example,dc=com", "password");
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry)
            {
                PageSize = int.MaxValue,
                Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))"
            };

            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");

            var result1 = searcher.FindOne();

Comment: It throws "Unknown error (0x80005000)" on FindOne()

Comment: it doesn't work like that, [check](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39zxbb5w(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would appreciate your help to help me out finding out the reason for that exception

Comment: @SimpleCode still getting that exception?

Comment: I have posted my answer using DirectoryEntry and it's working now

Comment: @SimpleCode perfect! If my question helped you resolving =>`Connecting to LDAP server throws NullReferenceException`, feel free to mark as the correct one, glad to help you

Answer (score 2):

Using **DirectoryEntry** it works for me as following:

```
using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ldap.forumsys.com:389/dc=example,dc=com", "", "", AuthenticationTypes.None)))
{
    searcher.Filter = "((objectClass=person))";
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");//email
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName");//first name
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn"); //last name
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("telephoneNumber");
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("description");
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf"); // groups

    var activeDirectoryStaffs = searcher.FindAll();
    if (activeDirectoryStaffs != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < activeDirectoryStaffs.Count; i++)
        {
            SearchResult result = activeDirectoryStaffs[i];
            var Email = result.Properties.Contains("mail") ? (string)result.Properties["mail"][0]:null;
            var Mobile = result.Properties.Contains("telephoneNumber") ? (string)result.Properties["telephoneNumber"][0] : null;
            var FirstName = result.Properties.Contains("givenName") ? (string)result.Properties["givenName"][0] : null;
            var LastName = result.Properties.Contains("sn") ? (string)result.Properties["sn"][0] : null;
            var Description = result.Properties.Contains("description") ? (string)result.Properties["description"][0] : null;

        }
    }
}
```